# Rails 3: No Method Error for Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in UploadStepsController#update

undefined method `attributes=' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000104775c40>


app/controllers/upload_steps_controller.rb:12:in `update'
```

I'm currently building a wizard that allows users to upload files, with the Wicked Wizard gem. What am I missing here?

**upload_steps_controller.rb**

```
class UploadStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :audience, :rewards, :review

def show
    @upload = current_user.uploads
    render_wizard
end

def update
    @upload = current_user.uploads
    @upload.attributes = params[:upload]
    render_wizard @upload
end


end
```

**upload.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :tagline, :category, :genre, :length, :description

belongs_to :user

validates :title, presence: true
validates :tagline, presence: true
validates :category, presence: true
validates :genre, presence: true
validates :length, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true

default_scope order: 'uploads.created_at DESC'
end
```

**new error**

```
NoMethodError in UploadStepsController#update
undefined method `save' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000010159c098>

app/controllers/upload_steps_controller.rb:13:in `update'
```

Comment: uploads looks like it is plural? attributes is for a single record.

Comment: it's plural because there can be multiple uploads for one user. is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

current_user.uploads is AREL object. So u have to specify what upload do u want to update. For example first user upload.

```
current_user.uploads.first.update_attributes(params[:upload])
```

or maybe

```
@upload = current_user.uploads.find(params[:upload].delete(:id))
@upload.update_attributes(params[:upload])
```

or all records

```
@upload = current_user.uploads
@upload.update_all(params[:upload])
```

Comment: I got errors with the attributes until I pasted this:            @upload = current_user.uploads(params[:upload])
@upload.update_all(params[:upload]).....now I'm getting a no method error, undefined method 'save'.....I'm assuming this has to do with the wicked wizard gem. Any suggestions with this?

Comment: Is upload active record model?

Comment: hm arel object...that means that u r using update_attributes on current_user.uploads....u have to use first or find ...or update_all

Comment: I need to explain this a little more clearly. What I need to do is to be able to allow a signed in user to upload a file, with several attributes to fill out associated with that file. I'm using a wizard to do this with the Wicked Wizard gem. I've been following this video to accomplish this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked. I've gotten up to 6:16 in the video, which is the current issue I'm having. Does this make things a bit clearer with what I need to do? Let me know what you think, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
@upload.update_attributes(params[:upload])
```

Answer (score 0):

@upload = current_user.uploads, it is given you the array of uploads object, but attributes methods is apply for single object. So you have to apply each methods

```
@uploads = current_user.uploads
@uploads.each do | upload|
  upload.update_attributes(params[:upload])
end
```